# Pyramid App Setup ../bin/python setup.py develop error: none

Tags: ubuntu, virtualenv, pyramid

I have a Pyramid app that I'm migrating to an Ubuntu server. I create the virtual environment `virtualenv env_name`, cd into the `env_name`, git clone the app, activate the environment `. ./bin/activate`, cd into `app_name`, and run `../bin/python setup.py develop`.

I get this outupt:

```
running develop
error: None
```

Nothing gets installed and the database initialize scripts do not get created. I tried the same process on my Mac laptop and everything works as expected. Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you satisfy prerequisites? IOW, is Pyramid installed for the version of Python used in your virtualenv? Which version of Python are you using? Suggest checking against the installation docs. http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/install.html#installing-pyramid-on-a-unix-system

Comment: If you cd into `app_name`, you may only need `python setup.py develop` if that's where the `setup.py` is located, instead of `../bin/python setup.py develop`.

Comment: @StevePiercy, yes Pyramid is installed in the virtualenv and the Python version is 2.7, the correct version.

Comment: @Raj, doing 'which python' shows I'm using the virtualenv copy of Python. I've tried running just 'python setup.py develop' with the same results.

Comment: I read again your steps. After you cd into `env_name`, you say you did `../bin/activate`. If that was successful, then your command prompt should have (env_name). I think the command should be relative to your current directory and use `source`, i.e., `source bin/activate`. This whole business of activating a virtual environment can easily get you wrapped around the axle. It's why we avoid the use of activate in the Pyramid docs. Suggest that you follow the instructions to install Pyramid to which I previously linked if you cannot get this to work using your preferred method with activate.

Answer (score -1):

How many python binaries are in your bin directory? I have had it where there were more than one, and I had to specify the specific one, like:

```
../bin/python3.3 setup.py develop
```

Also, I normally don't put my app directory within my virtualenv directory, so `env_name` and `app_name` would be at the same level.